# What maven repos to use for Google analytics java api?

Tags: java, maven, oauth, google-analytics

I'm trying to follow the guide here to use google analytics in my java application : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3

It says I just need this dependency

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev114-1.20.0'
}`

but this isn't enough to run the analytics-cmdline-sample project (linked on that page), it lacks the classes AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp and LocalServerReceiver

from some searching I found these dependencies which had the classes to run the sample:

`compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:1.20.0'`

I'm just a little confused- why didnt google explain that these dependencies are also needed? and why isnt there just a single parent dependency?